# how to add 2 hashmap into 1 by putting any condition on values

Tags: java

I have one hashmap having values {A=true, B=false, C=true} and another hashmap having values {A=false, B=false, C=false}
Now i want to create another hashmap having those element which are true in either one of the hashmap.
In short i have to merge both the hashmap using condition that value has to be true

Comment: Filter both to having true, merge filtered results.

Comment: You might consider using a bitset for an operation like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if you're trying to filter the entries or merge them. You can use [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to merge all values with the other map like this:

```
Map<String, Boolean> merged = new HashMap<>(map1);
merged.replaceAll((key, value) -> value || map2.get(key));
```

If you just want to filter, there's no point in storing the result in a map. Use a set instead:

```
Set<String> filtered = Stream.of(map1, map2)
        .map(Map::entrySet)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .filter(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```